# How to connect "disconnected" edge loops between vertices

Tags: vertices, edges

It's just simple question, look at these pictures:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to using loop and slice, but edge is not connected.

I tried to fix this, but it didn't worked(removing doubles, recalculate normals, remove faces that has not connected and re-fill it or etc).

What causes this, and how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file?

Comment: @Elmazz Sure, here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2NonO-YN8ayNzhCNU5vcjlCWGc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh is non manifold at these spots. There are faces inside the volume which you have to delete.[image: faceinside]